# Compare two NSDates for same date/time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

Is `date1 == date2` not a valid way to compare?  If not, what is the correct alternative?

Here's my code:

```
- (NSDate*) dateWithNoTime {
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:self];
    NSDate* dateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    return dateOnly;
}

- (BOOL) sameDayAsDate:(NSDate*)dateToCompare {
    NSDate *date1 = [self dateWithNoTime];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateToCompare dateWithNoTime];
    return date1 == date2;       // HERE IS WHERE THINGS SEEM TO FAIL

}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're comparing two pointer values. You need to use the NSDate comparison method like:

```
return ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame);
```

Comment: Isn't this called by `isEqual:`?

Answer (score 8):

As in the C language (of which Objective-C is a superset), the `==` (equality) operator compares two pointer values to see if they are equivalent (i.e. if two variables hold the same object). While this works in comparing primitive values (`int`s, `char`s, `bool`s), it does not work on Objective-C objects, which might be equal in content, but differ in memory location (which is what the equality operator compares).

To check if two objects are equal, `NSObject` offers an `-isEqual:` method which you can use as a general statement (e.g. `[date1 isEqual:date2]`), and some classes choose to offer a more specific comparison method, such as `-isEqualToDate:` used to compare `NSDate`s, or `-isEqualToString:` used to compare `NSString`s. These methods cannot be used to compare primitive types (`int`s, for instance) because those are not objects, but will work on almost all objects.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `==` in Objective-C to compare object equality (it will take the C meaning, comparing pointers). Like other languages, you are simply comparing the object pointers.

The message you want is `isEqualToDate:`, aka `[date1 isEqualToDate:date2]`

Comment: "You can never use `==` in Objective-C" is a little harsh. Of course you can use it, just not for the purpose Greg is asking about. Yes, what you wrote is correct, but the wording is weird.

Comment: isEqualToDate checks exact equality so it will probably never return true.