# NSDate if Statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I was wondering how I could use NSDate within an if statement - I want to update a UILabel depending what the date is, currently I have the following code to determine the date but don't know how to actually get this within an if statement.

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    dateLabel.text = dateString;

    if (dateString  == @"25/05/2012") {
        NSLog(@"It's the 25th!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not it's not...");
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629154/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-for-same-date-time-why-doesnt-this-code-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare two strings use `isEqualToString:`

```
if ([dateString isEqualToString:@"25/05/2012"]) {
    NSLog(@"It's the 25th!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not it's not...");
}
```

[isEqualToString: in NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_)

if you want to compare two `NSDate` use `isEqualToDate:`

```
[date1 isEqualToDate:date2]
```

[isEqualToDate: in NSDate class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-isEqualToDate_)

Answer (score 3):

To compare strings you can use [`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a) not `==` (with this you're comparing the pointers).
To compare dates you can use [`isEqualToDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate%3a).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually want to achieve you can use next calls:

**NSDate:**

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

**NSString:**

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, `==` checks for pointer equality. If you want to match the *contents* of an `NSString` or `NSDate`, or any other class of object, check that class' documentation for `isEqual...` and `compare...` methods. (`NSDate` has `isEqualToDate:` and `compare:`; `NSString` has `isEqualToString:` and `compare:` as well as several more specialized comparison methods.

However, depending on just what your aim is in matching dates, comparing `NSDates` with `isEqualToDate:` or checking the result of `compare:` against `NSOrderedSame` might not do what you want. An `NSDate` doesn't represent a whole calendar day but rather a specific moment in time. So if you have an `NSDate` representing `5/25/2012 1:53:13 AM PDT` and one representing `5/25/2012 1:55:01 AM PDT`, they will be equal or compare as `NSOrderedSame`.

What you're going for with the `NSDateFormatter` and string comparison will sort of work for checking whether two `NSDates` represent the same calendar day (presuming you compare string contents with `isEqualToString:` instead of using `==`), but it's sort of kludgy and will fail in certain edge cases that are more common than you think. Apple provides APIs specifically for such comparisons; there's [a section in the Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) that explains them well.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate provides

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Here is a category (found here http://webd.fr/637-comparer-deux-nsdate) that offers a neat way to compare NSDates:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (Compare)

-(BOOL) isLaterThanOrEqualTo:(NSDate*)date;
-(BOOL) isEarlierThanOrEqualTo:(NSDate*)date;
-(BOOL) isLaterThan:(NSDate*)date;
-(BOOL) isEarlierThan:(NSDate*)date;
//- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)date; already part of the NSDate API

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "NSDate+Compare.h"

@implementation NSDate (Compare)

-(BOOL) isLaterThanOrEqualTo:(NSDate*)date {
    return !([self compare:date] == NSOrderedAscending);
}

-(BOOL) isEarlierThanOrEqualTo:(NSDate*)date {
    return !([self compare:date] == NSOrderedDescending);
}
-(BOOL) isLaterThan:(NSDate*)date {
    return ([self compare:date] == NSOrderedDescending);

}
-(BOOL) isEarlierThan:(NSDate*)date {
    return ([self compare:date] == NSOrderedAscending);
}

@end
```

Simple to use:

```
if([aDateYouWant ToCompare isEarlierThanOrEqualTo:[NSDate date]]) // [NSDate date] is now
{
    // do your thing ...
}
```